# How to animate animation-list in Kotlin?

Tags: android, background, android-animation, kotlin

I have an `animation list` `XML` in `drawables`:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:duration="40" android:drawable="@drawable/animated_person_0 />
    <item android:duration="40" android:drawable="@drawable/animated_person_1 />
    <item android:duration="40" android:drawable="@drawable/animated_person_2 />
</animated-list>
```

I called the `list` from my `content_main.xml`:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/animatedPerson"
    android:src="@drawable/animatedperson"
    ...
/>
```

And now whatever I try with my code, I can't start the animation.

Comment: Show some code you have tried please.

Comment: It won't be helpful... I'm a beginner and I am not sure it would help. For example: animatedPerson.animate(). In Java, as far as I know, I should use android:background and getBackground.animate(). But I can't find similar thing in Kotlin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in Java it's like this:

```
// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

// Start the animation (looped playback by default).
frameAnimation.start();
```

So Kotlin will be really similar:

```
// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
val frameAnimation: AnimationDrawable = img.background as AnimationDrawable

// Start the animation (looped playback by default).
frameAnimation.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody asked, but i did it in ANKO, you don't need the background!? Just for somebody how whats to implement awesome animations…

I am a real ANKO fan!

loadinganim is the animation-list .xml

```
 loadingAnim = imageView{
   imageResource = R.drawable.loadinganim
  }

loadingAnim = loadingView.drawable as AnimationDrawable
loadingAnim.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin is similar to java...

// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.

```
val frameAnimation: AnimationDrawable = img.background as AnimationDrawable
```

// Start the animation (looped playback by default).

```
frameAnimation.start()
```

Another way is to use convert java code to kotlin by pressing ctrl + shift + a and then in action feild, write down

> convert java to Kotlin..

it will automatically convert the java code in kotlin.